# Fastlane/release automation for Android

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

Does anyone know a tool/project, like [fastlane](http://fastlane.tools), for Android release automation? With upload to the playstore... I know there is some task in fastlane for the Android-part, but it isn't read yet. [Fastlane Android Issue](https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane/issues/169)

I hope you guy's can help me out :)

Comment: Did you find a way to create new apps in Google Play? Fastlane for Android seems only to support updating existing apps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

fastlane is now available for Android projects as well: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Android.md

Answer (score 4):

Fastlane seems the best answer for this question. Additionally replying to Mr. Flibble's query about uploading new apps to Google Play via Fastlane, Google Play has a policy to upload new build via Dashboard only. No tools/scripts will be helpful in uploading new apps to Google Play dashboard.

Google Play allows user to upload max 15 binaries for new apps within 24 hour, therefore they don't allow us to upload new app binaries via Triple-T, Jenkins, Fastlane or any other scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Fastlane provides two major tools for Android now.

1. Screengrab
2. Supply

1) Screengrab (https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/screengrab)

screengrab generates localized screenshots of your Android app for different device types and languages for Google Play and can be uploaded using supply.

2) Supply (https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/)

supply uploads app metadata, screenshots and binaries to Google Play. You can also select tracks for builds and promote builds to production.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish new App using Fastlane, it not possible. You have to manually upload the apk to the google play store dashboard in the first time. You also need to finish content rating, select the countries you want to distribute and a bunch of other things. Otherwise you can't click that "publish" button.

However,if your app has already been created in Google play sotre, you can always use fastlane to update your app (edit store listing, upload newer version apk). Basically you need to:
1. Go to your google play account, do the create a service account and save  the json key.
2. Set up fastlane for your project using that json key and your app's application id. 
3. Use **supply** to do updates. 
The link in the above answers should help you figure it out.